# Read a 2GB file with peek or read

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

how can I know the last HEX byte of a 2GB binary file without opening the whole file..
is there an easy and fast way of doing this without running into memory problems?

Comment: Welcome to SO. When someone answers a question you had to your satisfaction you should accept it (http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). This makes it easier for people coming later with the same problem to quickly find the solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just Seek backwards from the end:

```
using (var br = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead(@"filename.2gb"))) {
    br.BaseStream.Seek(-1, SeekOrigin.End);
    Console.WriteLine(br.ReadByte()); // last byte
}
```

Comment: @XK8ER Since his solution works, accept then his solution as the answer by clicking on the check mark on the left.

Answer (score 1):

Just open a file and use [FileStream.Seek](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.seek.aspx) method to 2GB offset. This will be fast and will not cause any memory problems.